# Why should Class names and Constructors names be the same

Tags: c#, java, c++, class, constructor

So I've recently started to learn the basics of *Object Oriented Theory* and have been practicing this via java. My question is simple, 'Why should Class names and Constructors names be the same'?

Now I've read through this question->

[Why Constructor will always have same name as of class and how they are invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979612/why-constructors-will-always-have-same-name-as-of-class-and-how-they-are-invoked)

and even though this response makes sense, lower the use of keywords, it seems to me to make more sense to be able to name constructors differently and independently from the class. Now if I remember correctly (somewhat validated with a quick Google) the syntax goes like this:

```
 className objectName = New constructorName(variables)
```

So my point is you've already named the class you want to make an object from, What's the point of calling the same name again for the constructor? You might as well just write

```
 className objectName = New (vars);
```

seeing as the two give exactly the same information.

It seems to me that it would be far more semantic to be able to independently name your constructor in order to get a better idea what exactly it does e.g.

```
  thisClass thisObject = New thisConstructorMakesThis(vars)
```

Is there some documentation other than the response given in the link above that explains exactly why constructors and classes are named the same?

Also I notice that the response doesn't even explicitly mention the consideration of **dynamically named constructors**, rather an *"explicit syntax"* which sounds more like an absolute constructor name.

Comment: Note that in C++ you can say `Type t(arg1, arg2, arg3);`, so your calling the same name twice argument doesn't hold in that particular case.

Comment: Bjarne S. himself has written extensively on the design and evolution of C++, and a lot of it is available online. The discussions of the C++ working group is also available. (Besides, the base constructor case in C++ is the one without `new`, where there's no opportunity for constructor naming, and your example is better handled with a free (or static) function instead.)

Comment: Now, I'm not gonna lie, Losing 8 rep points felt like a beating. My hard earned 50 enabling me to comment, lost. Damn. Could someone explain why my question was down-voted so I can perhaps learn from this painful experience?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why constructors will always have same name as of class and how they are invoked implicitly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979612/why-constructors-will-always-have-same-name-as-of-class-and-how-they-are-invoked)

Comment: @Noodlemanny: I didn't downvote, but open-ended opinion-based questions (including "why does a language feature look/behave the way it does") are generally considered off-topic. You'll soon get the reputation back if you ask or answer more practical questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ at least, constructors do not have names. Some kind of syntax is needed to declare them, and it was decided to use something like function declaration syntax with the class name in place of a function name. There's no particular reason why that was chosen rather than some other name or some completely different syntax.

In any other context, the class name refers to the class, not the constructor.

Java and C# both acquired much of their syntax from C++, so they use the same convention. Other languages use other conventions, such as `__init__` in Python.

> You might as well just write 'className objectName = New (vars)', seeing as the two give exactly the same information.

Except that the variable is not always a reference to the same class that you're creating; it's often a reference to a base class:

```
base * thing = new derived;
```

So the new-expression *does* need to specify the type you want to create, separately from the type you want to refer to it as.

Also, these days you can often avoid repeating the class name:

```
auto p = std::make_shared<thing>(vars);
```

and of course C++ doesn't force dynamic allocation on you:

```
thing t(vars);
```

> It seems to me that it would be far more semantic to be able to independently name your constructor in order to get a better idea what exactly it does

You can always write a named "factory" function (like `make_shared`, for example) to create and return an object, if you need more expressiveness than the declaration or new-expression syntax allows.

Comment: And if it's C++, you'll often not be using `new` at all: `ClassName obj(vars);` does the trick nicely, without any repetition of the class name.

Comment: With `auto object = initializer;`, we often don't need to name the type *at all*.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed. I was trying to steer clear of too much language-specific advice, but it's certainly worth noting that C++ doesn't force dynamic allocation on you.

Answer (score 6):

When you write `new Identifier`, `Identifier` isn't the name of the constructor, it's the name of the class. It's often the same as the variable's class, but it's not always. 
The static type of a variable need not match the class being instantiated. For example:

```
Collection<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you didn't write the class name, and wrote instead:

```
className objectName = new(vars);
```

What would happen outside the context of a variable initialization? What if you had an inline `new` call, such as:

```
linkedList.next = new Node(value, null);
```

Here `Node` isn't redundant; it's the only mention of the class. If you were to omit `Node`, how would the compiler know what class to instantiate?

Comment: I think I understand your answer. 'Specificity' or whatever similar what have you, isn't really my strong point.

Answer (score 0):

You can have constructors that are differently named (although there is still the default constructor hidden behind a private scoping.)

Look at Singletons...

MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();

Comment: That's not a constructor.

Comment: Well again you're still listing the same name twice, for no explicit reason. Like with Johns response the double naming adds no clarity.

Comment: I guess its just how Java is written, It expects a constructor called the name of the class or its parent up till it reaches Object.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is a special function that consturcts the class (creates the object), so therefore it is fully logical to have the same name. That is the way C# is defined and other languages. Constructors are special things. They can't be called, they can be instantiated.